# A simple picture for the temperature vs density curve?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, temperature, phase-transition

Consider $N$ particles interacting through a 6-12 Lennard-Jones pair potential (defined with particle radius $\sigma$ and energy barrier $\epsilon$) within a closed volume $V$ and evolving with Newtonian mechanics with fixed total energy ("NVE" ensemble). Plotting the temperature of this system (defined as the mean kinetic energy) against the density ($\rho=\frac{N \sigma^{3}}{V}$) shows an inverse parabola-like structure with a peak around $\rho=0.4$.

The decrease of temperature during the increase of the density ("the right part of the peak") may be intuitive, because the densified liquid structure has more potential energy and probabky therefore less kinetic energy. But why does the temperature increase as a function of density before that ("the left part of the peak") ? This structure is commonly identified with the liquid/vapor phase-coexistence line. More specifically, it is also characterized with a critical exponent ($\gamma = \frac{1}{2}$) and it seems to be valid for many systems. But I still can not explain with a simple picture this non-monotonic behavior.

I think the initial increase in temperature is a consequence of the increase of total energy as density is increased, because of the higher potential energy. While the subsequent decrease in temperature results from the ordering and the more stable liquid structures formed at higher densities. Is this the correct interpretation ?

After the inverse-parabola shape in the $\rho -T$ plane, the temperature shows very drastic increase as a function of density, and further increasing the density after this stage leads to a solid. Althouhg this phase-diagram is very well-known, and I can reproduce it here with a very simple setup, I still do not clearly understand why there is an increase of temperature during solidification. What is the intuition behind this ?

To summerize the questions, why does temperature decrease on the vapor/liquid line and increase on the liquid/solid line ? Why do these two transitions involve different temperature behavior while they are both related with ordering ?

Comment: So my first question is what determines the total energy here, which leads to the broader question of how are these curves being calculated? What sort of initial conditions are being used and how are they changing to accommodate extra particles?

Comment: The total energy is just the sum of potential energy and kinetic energy, it is constant for a given simulation run. The temperature is just the kinetic energy. The density is the particle number divided by the volume, which are both fixed quantities. The density is changed by simply making the volume larger and keeping particle number same. Initial conditions are uniformly distributed particles in the cubic cell. But please note that I am asking with regard to this general result, rather for my particular setup. I refered to my setup just to have a concrete simple case as basis.